# Recreating table using JPA, Kotlin and @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, collections, hibernate-mapping

I have weird problem. This is my code:

```kotlin
@Table(name = "rank")
@Entity
data class Rank(
        @Id
        private val id: String,

        @Embedded
        private var rankValue: RankValue,

        @ElementCollection
        @CollectionTable(
                name="rank_change",
                joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "rank_id")]
        )
        private val set: MutableSet<RankChange>

) {

    fun calculateDifference(loseRank: Rank, rankPolicy: RankPolicy): Double {
        return rankPolicy.calculateRankDifference(rankValue.value, loseRank.rankValue.value)
    }

    fun addChange(difference: Double, now: LocalDateTime, sparringId: String? = null) {
        rankValue = rankValue.apply(difference)
        set.add(RankChange(date = now, value = difference, sparringId = sparringId))
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Embeddable
data class RankChange(
        @Column(name = "date")
        private val date: LocalDateTime,

        @Column(name = "value")
        private val value: Double,

        @Column(name = "sparring_id")
        private val sparringId: String? = null
)
```

When I add element to `MutableSet<RankChange>` hibernate deletes "rank_change" table and insert row by row. Maybe should I implement equals and hash code contract or use `MutableList<T>` and add `@OrderColumn` annotation ? But I really don't need order.

Comment: What's so weird about it? Elements in an `ElementCollection` don't have an identity, so JPA has no notion of a 'previously existing' element in an `ElementCollection`

Comment: Ok, but can I change this behavior ? I my case I would like to insert row only.

Comment: The solution is pretty simple: give the objects identities, i.e. make them entities and give them an `id`

Comment: Ok, but don't You think that it's artificial ? `RankChange` isn't an Entity - it only value object.

Comment: Identity or lack thereof is precisely the difference between entities and value objects. You're essentially saying: 'this object is not an entity, it doesn't need identity' and at the same time, 'JPA needs to **identify** the objects to tell which of them previously existed and then only insert the new ones, without rewriting all the rows'. You can't have your cake and eat it, too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ElementCollection` behaves like unidirectional `@OneToMany` in that sense it deletes all the rows and inserts elements from the in-memory collection one by one.

To avoid this you could create a separate entity to hold the elements and make the (`@OneToMany` - `@ManyToOne`) relationship bidirectional (with `mappedBy` on the parent side and `@JoinColumn` on the child side).

Comment: So do You suggest to change `RankChange` from embeddable to entity ?

Comment: Ok, and is it possible to have @ElementCollection without recreating data ? :D

Comment: @Bambelal no, that's the point. There is no dirty checking on this collection and those object's identities are different in the database and in java. Note, that the database has no idea, what java's `equals` mean and since hibernate is not tracking the changes of the elements without id, is simply uses the current state to recreate the collection in the database

Comment: And what about this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-unidirectional-collections-with-jpa-and-hibernate/  ?

Comment: @Bambelal mind the note: "So, the JPA provider will most likely assume that the combination of all of the fields in the Embeddable is unique, in combination with the foreign key (JoinColumn(s)). This, however, could be inefficient, or just not feasible if the Embeddable is big, or complex." It's an assumption, it's vendor-specific and is not always the case.